# Not able to save edits to vector layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, editing

I have a vector layer with about 200 features. So far I have been able to add polygons to this layer just fine, now it is giving me trouble. When I draw the polygon and try to save edits, the polygon disappears. In a few cases the polygon is saved successfully though it is rare. Then occassionaly the polygon disappears but the attributes that are assigned do appear in the attribute table. Any suggestions how to get through this?

Comment: Have you tried saving the vector layer as a new shapefile and making sure that the new shapefile is loaded? I had a similar problem where my polygons kept disappearing and it was because I loaded 2 vector layers but they were based on the same shapefil. However, your situation could be completely different.

Comment: Joseph, Your idea worked. I appreciate the help very much. One other thing is arising with this now though. Though the new shapefile lies at the top of the layer tree it is being covered by my aerial imagery layer. I'm looking through properties to see if anything is causing this and I don't see anything. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: That sounds like an overlap. If you go to _Layer order_ (the tab should be availabe at the bottom of the _Layers_ window interface), check the rendering order box and then play around with the ordering.

Answer (score 5):

Reiterating the comments as an answer for the convenience of others:

Always make sure that each layer has a **unique** shapefile associated with it, otherwise data losses will be likely if more than one layer is based on the same shapefile and you edit its attributes.

Comment: I created a map layout that has two different map displays. I have created duplicate layers of some of my data so that I can show different symbology for the same data in the two different map displays. So am I then at greater risk of data loss?

Comment: Hi Caleb, apologies for the late reply. Depending on how your symbologies are set for each layer (ie. if the symbology is based on the same attribute columns) then editing that attribute **could** affect the different layers. If you want to edit an attribute column of one layer and then save it, any edits you make on the same column in a duplicate layer **will** overwrite the attributes. So you have to be careful :)